# What is preventing me from being able to use a CSS stylesheet in the web.py framework?

Tags: python, html, css, web.py

I am working through Learn Python The Hard Way, and am currently working through exercise 51. In it, the student is asked to try building out some basic web applications using the web.py framework. The first study drill is to improve the quality of the HTML layouts so that the applications are built on well-formatted pages. I am looking to make a template layout that applies to all pages in the application, and leverages a CSS stylesheet to provide the formatting. I would like for the CSS formatting to be external, rather than within the HTML file. For some reason, no matter how I format the path to 'main_layout.css' I cannot get the formatting changes to take effect. I have tried the path with a leading '/' and without the leading '/'. I have tried moving the CSS file into another folder (the root folder, and the templates folder). I tried emptying my browser cache in case that was causing in issue. I tried accessing the 'static' directory and the 'main_layout.css' file itself directly through my browser, which I was able to do in both cases--the files is in there, but I can't get it to accept the formatting markup from 'main_layout.css'. I googled this issue, checked the google group for web.py, and searched stackoverflow--in all cases, the answers were related to the path to the css file, which I believe I have fully explored and attempted to fix to no avail.I have tried all suggestions I could find on the web, and I am stumped. My code is as follows:

```
/bin
    app.py
/ex51
/static
    main_layout.css
/templates
    hello_form.html
    index.html
    layout.html
/tests
```

app.py is written as follows:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'Index'
    )

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html written as follows:

```
$def with (greeting)

$if greeting:
    I just wanted to say <em style="color: green; font-size: 2em;">$greeting</em>
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
```

hello_form.html written as follows:

```
<h1>Fill out this form</h1>

<form action="/hello" method="POST">
    A Greeting: <input type="text" name="greet">
    <br/>
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

main_layout.css written as follows:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }

.container {
    width:800px;
    }

.container #body_container {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    }

.container #footer_container {
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    }
```

and layout.html:

```
$def with (content)

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main_layout.css" />
        <title>This is My Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" id="body_container">

            $:content

        </div>

        <div class="container" id="footer_container">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: One additional bit of information--I am running this script from the PowerShell of my Windows 7 PC, and accessing it at `http://localhost:8080/hello` through Google Chrome.

Comment: One additional comment: I am running this script off of my own Windows 7 PC through the powershell, and then accessing it through "http://localhost:8080/hello".

Comment: You can, and should, edit your question rather than putting addition information in comments.

Comment: Also, have you actually looked at the rendered output? Have you checked that your server actually serves the CSS file?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback--I have made an edit to the original question for clarification. I have looked at the rendered output, and it is in plaintext, which isn't incorporating my CSS. My goal is to get the page to render with the specified CSS formatting through my browser.

Comment: It's not going to incorporate your css. You are specifying that the browser should separately request the CSS file. This is why it matters whether the CSS file can be requested by the browser. You should probably read a bit about the structure of the web to figure out how it all fits together.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you--I can access styles.css from the browser by pointing the browser to `http://localhost:8080/static/styles.css`. However when I include the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">` in my code, I am unable to get the CSS formatting specified in the CSS file.

Comment: Right, that's what I was asking about. The next step is to ensure that your browser is requesting it (use the requests tab in whatever you're using on the browser side to see what your page is doing).

Comment: Doing what you said (figuring out if the browser is requesting it) did the trick. I found that my browser was, indeed, requesting it, and that *some* of my CSS was being applied. I had some basic CSS errors that were tripping me up within my CSS file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are commenting out the CSS file using a octothorp (#) which is incorrect for a CSS document (but correct for Python, which is where the confusion is). Use /* to comment out your code in a CSS document. Like this:

```css
.container /*body_container*/ {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```